# Python Tkinter. How to center a Label in a Frame of fixed size?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

[The first textline should be centered as should be the picture and the button. The second textline should be aligned to the left.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYdSK.jpg)

As described above, I would like some elements centered (widthwise). The window should be fixed.
I tried using columns before, but I dont quite understand how I can assign a grid to a Frame and have a Label abide by it.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()


root.title("Programm zum setzen von Bildpunkten")
root.geometry("400x400")
root.resizable(width=False,height=False)



#Frames
Frame_1 = tk.Frame(master=root,bg="#c4c2bb",width=400,height=40)
Frame_2 = tk.Frame(master=root,bg="#c4c2bb",width=400,height=40)
Frame_3 = tk.Frame(master=root,bg="#c4c2bb",width=400,height=280)
Frame_4 = tk.Frame(master=root,bg="#c4c2bb",width=400,height=40)

Frame_1.grid_propagate(0)
Frame_2.grid_propagate(0)
Frame_3.grid_propagate(0)
Frame_4.grid_propagate(0)


#Main Containers layout
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=2) 
root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=2) 
root.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=0)

#Frame Position
Frame_1.grid(row=0,sticky="nw")
Frame_2.grid(row=1,sticky="ew")
Frame_3.grid(row=2,sticky="ew")
Frame_4.grid(row=3,sticky="new")

#Frame_1 Widgets
Start_message = tk.Label(master = Frame_1, text=Message_start,bg="#c4c2bb",fg="black")

#Frame_2 Widgets
Number_text = tk.Label(master = Frame_2, text=Number_Pictures,bg="#c4c2bb",fg="black")

#Frame_4 Widgets
#Start_button = tk.Button(master = Frame_4, text=Button_start_text,width=30,height=10,fg="white")

#Frame_1 Widget Position
Start_message.grid(row=0)
Anzahl_text.grid(row=0)

#Frame_3 Image, Dimension 200x200
Logo = Image.open("Logotest.jpg")
Logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Logo)
Logo_label = tk.Label(master = Frame_3,image=Logo)
Logo_label.grid(row=0)
   

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Not related to your problem but you know how you pass the `master` keyword to all tkinter widgets. You should do the same with `ImageTk.PhotoImage(Logo)` => `ImageTk.PhotoImage(Logo, master=Frame_3)`. It can save you a headache later down the line.

Comment: @TheLizzard: I've never done that and I've never had a headache from leaving `master` out when creating images. The headache is when you create multiple instances of `Tk`.

Comment: @BryanOakley It is always a good idea to pass in the `master` keyword argument. You wouldn't advise OP to remove the `master=root` from `Frame_1 = tk.Frame(master=root, ...)` even though it isn't going to have an effect (unless OP creates multiple instances of `Tk()`). I consider passing in the `master` keyword argument a convention. That is why I advice everyone to just pass in the `mater` key word argument.